# What happens when we write 0 to a GPIO

Tags: embedded, avr, gpio

I want to know what happens when we write "0" to a GPIO (the actual intention is to pull down the output).

I'm not sure whether the controller pulls down the GPIO pin and connects it internally to ground or it simply disconnects the pin internally and makes it disconnected from the peripheral (LED) connected to it from the micro controller.

The actual task for me is:

I have to send a 8 bit data from 4 gpio pins(Ex PORTA4-7). So to do this I have to write the higher bits(D4-D7) then (D0-D3).

My approach is:

```
% Writing the higher bits first
PORTA=PORTA|(DATA & 0xF0);

%Writing the lower bits
PORTA=PORTA|((DATA & 0x0F)<<4);
```

The main doubt is "Will this piece of code disturb the remaining GPIO (PORTA0-3)". Because I am connecting them to 4 ADC inputs.

Comment: depends on your hardware and how you have configured it as to what happens.

Comment: PORTA=PORTA|(DATA & 0xF0); needs to be PORTA=(PORTA&0x0F)|(DATA & 0xF0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to understand how GPIO are coupled together is to just visit the datasheet. TI's MSP430 datasheet's are an excellent example.

- [MSP430F551X Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/msp430f5529)

The Input/Output sections have very explicit illustrations on how the GPIO registers interact with the IO Pads themselves. Here is Port P1.0-P.17 (from page 80 of Datasheet above).

[image]

**Outputs**

The basic takeaway for you here is that:

- Writing a '0' to P1OUT.x (e.g bit0 is P1OUT.0) will drive the output low if the IO pad is in output mode.

Here is a simpler reduced version of that:

[image]

**Inputs**

Similarly, here is an inspection of using the IO pad in 'input' mode

[image]

The basic takeaway for you here is that writing to P1OUT.x here has no effect on the output; the output buffer is tri-stated!

**Hazards**

If your program shares a single GPIO port-register amongst several tasks, then you must ensure access to this register is **thread-safe**. For embedded systems this usually just means 'make sure ISRs don't screw things up'. Consider -

```
//... (from main thread)
P1OUT = P1OUT | 0x02;

//... (from some ISR)
P1OUT = P1OUT | 0x01;
```

this generally translates to the following dissassembly

```
//... (from main thread)
mov  P1OUT,  %some_reg
operate on %some_reg
mov   %some_reg, P1OUT

//... (from some ISR)
mov  P1OUT,  %some_reg
operate on %some_reg
mov   %some_reg, P1OUT

//and then the time series looks like   (P1OUT = 0 initially)
[0]:  mov P1OUT,  %some_reg_main_thread  (%reg_m = 0)
[1]:  or  0x02,   %some_reg_main_thread  (%reg_m = 2)
[2]:  ISR fires!
[3]:  mov P1OUT,  %some_reg_isr_thread   (%reg_i = 0)
[4]:  or  0x01,   %some_reg_isr_thread   (%reg_i = 1)
[5]:  mov %some_reg_isr_thread, P1OUT    (P1OUT  = 1)
[6]:  ISR exits
[7]:  mov %some_reg_main_thread, P1OUT   (P1OUT  = 2)

(end result: P1OUT=2, but should be 3 (0x01 | 0x02))
```

Also, IO Pads aren't as simple as they seem and you should always visit the datasheet to understand just how bad/delicate/confusing/etc it is.

For example in the TI example above, the following hazards apply to your original question:

(while P1DIR.x = 0)

- P1REN.x + P1OUT.x

  - if P1REN.x is '1', and you toggle P1OUT.x, **that toggles the pullup resistor on and off too**

[image]

Of course, IO pad topologies are MCU-specific. I'd recommend reviewing the IO-Pad topology in your datasheet before moving forward on your project. It should be your best-friend.

**Code Practices**

Consider using the |=, &= and ^= operators when you can, e.g.:

```
P1OUT |= (1<<2)+(1<<3)   //assert pin2 & pin3 high
```

and when you can't, consider using packed structures, or **unit-tested** encapsulation routines:

```
struct myporta {
    uint    b3_0    : 4;     //use unsigned int-type
    uint    b4      : 1;
    uint    b5_10   : 6;
    uint    b25_b11 : 15;
    uint    b26     : 1;
    uint    b31_27  : 5;
} __attribute__ ((packed));  //gcc syntax

...
//write to my LED
myporta *porta = &PORTA;   //if you w

porta->b26 = 1;            //turn the led on
```

nothing is worse than gpio clobbering one another!

Answer (score 1):

The MCU will actively drive the pin low, you can think of it as grounding the pin, [more info here](http://www.w9xt.com/page_microdesign_pt3_ouput_basics.html).

```
PORTA=PORTA|(DATA & 0xF0);
```

This will not affect the 4 lower pins, but it is still not correct. If PORTA is already set high and data contains zeroes, you will not drive the pins low. You want to mask out the relevant parts of DATA and you only want to preserve the part of PORTA that you aren't changing:

```
PORTA = (PORTA & 0x0F) | (DATA & 0xF0);
```

and then similarly for setting the 4 lsb:

```
PORTA = (PORTA & 0xF0) | (DATA & 0x0F);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, writing to PORTA will disturb all the bits, even if some of them are designated inputs with DDRA.

You will have to make sure you are not writing to the higher bits while taking ADC readings on the lower bits.

Even something like

```
% Writing the higher bits first
PORTA=PORTA|(DATA & 0xF0);

%Writing the lower bits
PORTA=PORTA|((DATA & 0x0F)<<4);
```

will not work. Reading PORTA on the right side of the assignment will get some value for its pins, either 0 or 1, even if the voltage is somewhere in between. That value will then be written to the same pin, driving it high or low momentarily.

Comment: Can u suggest me a way by which i can write data to just four gpio without touch other. and code snippet?  Thnks

Comment: No. The byte gets written all at once. That's kind of the point I am making. Your options are to use different ports, or to do the writing and ADC at different times. I don't know how you are structuring the flow of execution. How about setting a flag while you are taking the ADC values, and checking that flag before each write?

Comment: Hmm,, the approach that you are saying is good,, i will modify it... Thanks for your reply